# How to save a Memo or RichEdit as UTF 8 text file?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

i am using Delphi 7, I wrote a program that  get some information from user, combines info from several editboxes and memos and other input components in a memo. How can I save this Memo as a UTF 8 text file?
I received some files from last program's users without a solution for utf problem and now, when i open the output file i see ???? (as you know!) instead of different language characters, these are not recoverable, are they?

Comment: Delphi 7 GUI is native ANSI only. So you'll need to properly set the character set of all controls and use `UTF8Encode` and `UTF8Decode` to *bridge* between them and the file data. Note that, since only ANSI is supported, you won't be able to have multiple character sets in a single control.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like this:

```
const
  UTF8BOM: array[0..2] of Byte = ($EF, $BB, $BF);
var
  UTF8Str: UTF8String;
  FS: TFileStream;
begin
  UTF8Str := UTF8Encode(Memo1.Text);

  FS := TFileStream.Create('C:\path to\file.txt', fmCreate);
  try
    FS.WriteBuffer(UTF8BOM[0], SizeOf(UTF8BOM));
    FS.WriteBuffer(PAnsiChar(UTF8Str)^, Length(UTF8Str));
  finally
    FS.Free;
  end;
end;
```